# Authorization issues with MS Graph

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

So I have been using powershell for quite a while now and am somewhat familiar with getting a token from an Azure application using MS Graph configured with application API permissions.  I am now attempting to perform the same in a python console application and am getting flummoxed as I constantly get a 400 error.  here's the snippet of my code...

```
import requests
import json
app_id='<appid>'
client_secret='<client secret>'
token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2    /v2.0/token'
token_data = {
 'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
 'client_id': app_id,
 'client_secret': client_secret,
 'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
 'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
}
headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, json=token_data)
token = token_r.json().get('access_token')
```

any ideas?

Comment: do you actually have real values for <appid>, <client secret>, and <tentant id>? Also, there is a gap in your url: ".../oath2    /v2.0/..."

Comment: I've double checked, the URL was posted incorrctly, there is no space in the code.  The AppId and secret are correct.  A similar set of cmds in powershell work.  Here's the powershell code that works.:

Comment: $clientId = "<clientID>"
$tenantName = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$clientSecret = "<Client Secret>"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
 
 
$ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_Id     = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 
 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

Comment: I've also just tried forcing the data to be json string format by altering the post line to token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=json.dumps(token_data)) still get a 400 error

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I needed to add the oAuth2 requests library.  See sample code below:

```
    import requests
    import json
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
    from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
    app_id='<app id>'
    client_secret='<client Secret>'
    token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/tennantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    scope='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=app_id, scope=scope, grant_type="client_credentials")
    session = OAuth2Session(client=client, scope=scope)
    # fill access token
    token = session.fetch_token(token_url=token_url,client_id=app_id,scope=scope,client_secret=client_secret)
```